# Architecture for distributed data storage

Tags: java, storage, activemq-classic, distributed-system

Currently I have two separated applications.

First is RESTful API.

Second is data storage that can process raw data and store processed data on the file system. This data grouped by folders and folder ids are grouped by user ids.

These applications connected through message queue (ActiveMQ) using queueCount queues.

Files sending also through this queue using embedded fileserver.

I want to distribute this data storage across several nodes.

1) First variant

On each of n nodes set up ActiveMQ and current storage application.
Create master node that will be serve queries to these shards.
In this way data for the different users will be stored on different nodes.

2) Second

Set up n nodes with storage app. Set up one instance for ActiveMQ. Create n*queueCount queues in ActiveMQ. Consume messages from corresponding queues from storage nodes.

But both variants are not perfect, maybe you can give advice to me?
Thanks in advance

Update: 
What is the best way to evenly distribute data based on uuid?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a distributed file system like hdfs to distribute your data store. This way replication is covered, data is distributed and you can use hadoop to even send jobs to process your data in parallel.

Comment: Because I want to distribute load, processing of data may heavy load processor, I need more nodes to process many different users simultaneously.

Comment: Go with the first option which uses one queue. If the load is significantly high, thereby publishing rate is higher than consume rate, you can easily attach consumers and thereby scale. By the way, i've recently came across twitter storm https://storm.apache.org which looks very good for such topologies

Comment: It will be good if ActiveMQ will contain as many queues? And would not it be no problem with it performance?

Comment: I'd use one queue just as you can see here http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html where publishers and consumers can come and go but the queue is static except if your going to have a backup. Its a significant overhead to have one queue per consumer

Comment: Maybe there is some way to consume different types of messages for different consumers from one queue? E.g. based on some header?

Comment: don't know how activemq works but in zeromq you're messages have an identifier, a header and the content. you could look into it for activemq but i find it easier to just create your own mesage protocol for example MSG_TYPE|MSG_CONTENT or something more serious with json

Answer (score 0):

@vvsh, what you are attempting is distributed storage with load-balancing (but I did not understand how you plan to keep specific user's files on a specific node and at the same time get even load distribution). Any way, before I go any further, the mechanism you are attempting is quite difficult to achieve in a stable manner, instead, consider using some of the infrastructures mentioned in the comments, they may not 100% fit your requirement but will do a much better job.

Now, to achieve even distribution, your architecture essentially needs to be some kind of hub-spoke model, where the hub (in your case master server) will collect the load from a single queue with multiple JMS clients running on multiple thread. The master server has to essentially do the round-robin dispatching (you may choose different types of schemes, based on file number, if file sizes are fairly constant or file size and net total dispatched to a node).

The persistence agents must run on every node to actually take the files, process them and persist in the datastore. The communication between the master and the agents could be through web service or direct socket (depending on the performance you require), the Q based communication with the agents could potentially chock your JMS server.

One point of observation is that the files could be staged in another location, like a Document/CMS and only the ID could be communicated to the master as well as the agents, there by reducing the network load and JMS persistence load.

The above mechanism needs to toke care of exceptions, failures and re-dispatching i.e. guaranteed delivery, horizontal scaling, concurrency handling, and optimized for performance. In my view you shall be better off using some proven infrastructure but if you really want to do it, the above architecture will get the job done.

Comment: I want to evenly distribute data, not load. Each node will be process it own data.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'evenly distribute data'

Comment: For example I have 1000 users and 10 nodes. I want that each node contains data of about 100 users, because each user will be have almost same amount of data.

Comment: Same mechanism as above would work, only instead of round-robin, you will have specific user to node mapping. Just out of curiosity are you implementing this on production or testing out for knowledge/learning?

Comment: Application without distributed architecture is already ready and work on test servers in google cloud.
But it my personal project and I don't know whether or not it will be published.